# How to control the Dynamixel Motor in PWM mode without having it locked when PWM is zero

Tags: dynamixel

I want the motor to be free to move by hand when I set the PWM to zero. Instead, there is a torque that makes the motor still in one position. Is that possible to do?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Jose P. Borges, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I think what @jsotola means to say is that you haven't given us any specific part number, so we can't reference any datasheets on your behalf. As I state above, though, this is a specific question about a specific motor from a specific manufacturer - you'll probably get a better answer and faster if you ask the manufacturer directly. That said, some motors have an "Enable" bit or similar that energizes the windings, and you would need to clear this bit to get the behavior you want. Again, this should all be covered in the datasheet, but the OEM should be able to tell you, too.